# Energy efficiency and window frames

Tags: windows, energy-efficiency

I am trying to better insulate a few rooms in our home that run colder than others. We have floor to ceiling windows at one end our house, which I understand will generally make the area colder, but I am trying to determine if there is anything I can do to improve energy efficiency.

I noticed that our floor to ceiling windows have what appear to be significant gaps between the frame and the casing. I can’t tell for certain, but there might be a small draft coming in through the gap.

Should I be sealing this gap with caulk in order to improve energy efficiency?

[image: Gaps around floor to ceiling window frames]

Comment: Air sealing is never a bad idea. Any chance your local utility offers a subsidized energy audit service? Ours does. They will give you a good report of spots to address for efficiency.

Comment: We can't really see enough here.  Are these windows that don't open?

Comment: Do you have whole house air conditioning? It's likely the rooms are cold because the ducting system is balanced for summer A/C loads, or for a compromise between sunmer and winter.   "Solar gain" is 300 BTU/hr per square foot of sunlight, and that is the bulk of your A/C load.  So rooms that get punished by solar gain in summer are often different rooms than chill the most in the winter.  It's a real design problem with single-zone forced air systems.

Comment: To me, it looks like the sash hasn't been fully closed into the frame. Unlock the sash lock, then push the upper sash _all_ the way into the frame, then relock it. Applying caulk here will also leave the gap where the two sashes meet leaking air and that will need to be caulked, too. There might even be a gap if the bottom sash isn't fully closed, leaving another gap to be caulked. This will leave you with a completely inoperable window that still won't seal/insulate as well as if it were simply properly/completely closed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can ask your utility.  I asked mine a few years ago and they said they would rent me their thermal imaging camera or provide a paid service.  So I purchased one from Ebay.  They are not expensive.

Heres one on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CL56R4RY)

I wouldn't rely on it for accurate measurements, but for comparison they are perfect.  Go outside after dark, point at each door and window and attack the one thats losing the most heat.

You can check if there is an airgap by placing  wet finger close to it, it will feel cooler faster than in other places, if there is a leak. Sealing it will definitely help.

Another thing that helps is long drapes, but the drapes must touch the floor along the width and be wide enough to cover the window completely.

[image]

Comment: Check your local library before buying or renting a one-time tool like a thermal camera. Some now have a "library if things" service, which might be have the tool and let you check it out for a specific length of time. Exact rules and availability will vary, of course.

Comment: Here in the US, many auto parts stores have free rentals of tools and you _might_ find a thermal imaging camera there. ("Free" = pay to purchase the tool, then return and get a full refund. Forget to return it and you've already purchased it.) Also there are many tool rental companies where you _might_ be able to rent a high quality camera for a day for less than it would cost to buy a cheap one.